# From WatchOS App connect BLE device using iPhone Bluetooth

Tags: ios, watchos

Hi everyone here it's my problem, I have an simple app on my Apple Watch and iPhone. All my goal is using iPhone minimum on the App. Instead of iPhone App I want to use this App mostly from the watch. So I have an UI screen consisting with 2 buttons (Scan and Connect) on the watch. And these buttons should control the iPhone's Bluetooth. I don't want to use Watch Bluetooth. Considering all, is it posibble to trigger the iPhone Bluetooth in background from Watch and connect iPhone to a BLE device.

**I think I fix this problem with your help guys;**

Hi again, I believe I can fix this problem with the background transfers. Let me first explain the problem better when I want to use iPhone App local database and also want to use iPhone's Bluetooth from the Watch App I had trouble. And then I noticed sending messages from Watch to iOS wakes up iOS in the background (Source for more detail). In this way I'll have using iPhone app only in background and even scan BLE devices from the iPhone in bg and send them to the Watch App (WC Sessions).

*Source (Communicate with iPhone and Watch)*

https://medium.com/@jackywangdeveloper/apple-watch-communication-with-iphone-af84d51ff810

Comment: Welcome Haluk, if you show us what you have done so far, I think you can find someone to help your problem.

Comment: @AtalayAsa Actually I've not done so far, as I said I've a default iPhone App with WatchKit. Before I start I want to learn is it possible to control iPhone's Bluetooth in background from the Watch and How. My goal is do not wakin up the iPhone App. :)

Comment: You can't control anything on the phone directly. Your watch app will need to communicate with your iPhone app and the iPhone app will need to use Core Bluetooth to perform whatever tasks you want.

Comment: @Paulw11 Yeah I know it, I am using WatchConnectivity and it's sessions. Also use CB too. What I am looking for is while scanning devices with communicated iPhone in background get scanned devices list from iPhone to the Watch App.

Comment: So why can't you use the WCSession to get the scanned devices from the phone?

Comment: @Paulw11 yeah Paul it was my bad. Using iPhone in background and communicate with it via sessions will work for me. :) I edited the post. Thx guys.